# Как предотвратить ошибки связанные с прерыванием выполнения скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Допустим мы записываем два значения в localStorage:

```
localStorage.a = "...";
// Прерывание выполнения скрипта.
localStorage.b = "...";
```

Можно ли объединить эти инструкции так, чтобы в результате прерывания выполнения скрипта (по каким либо системным или аппаратным ошибкам) оба значения не были записаны?

Comment: а каким образом прерывают скрипт?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Прерывание выполнения скрипта может произойти по каким либо системным или аппаратным ошибкам. Я тестировал с задержкой записи "b" через `setTimeout`, можно добиться того чтобы была записана только "a" при закрытии вкладки например. Конечно это маловероятно, но возможно.

Comment: у localStorage транзакций нет. но они есть у IndexedDB.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman А самому их реализовать на JS не получится?